# VM keeps deallocating

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, microsoft

Hi I have a Linux VM and it has been automatically deallocated about 7 times today. The activity log does not show this. I don't know why this is happening. But it is rendering the VM basically unusable. I'm being made to pay to create a technical support ticket. Can anyone help here? (I'm sure you need more information, but I'm afraid I don't know where to look for you, as I said the activity log doesn't mention the deallocation, although I know I saw this information somewhere).
Thanks
John
OMG, now I see that Azure sent me here but this isn't even an Azure website. Hilarious. Please disregard this post. I'm paying for a service and Microsoft should support it...

Comment: The most common reason for a VM being deallocated is that you have reached a limit on your subscription, are you using a free sub, or have a a spending limit or amount of free credit that may have run out?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you select 'No' on Azure Spot Instance option when creating the VM.

Azure Spot Instance allows you to have a VM at a much lower price because Azure may have excessive resource from time to time, but it can evict (shutdown) your VM at any time when it needs its resource back.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/spot-vms

Other reasons may include your payment method is invalid or you have ran out of free credits as mentioned by Sam.